# Запуск приложения в режиме "разделение экрана"

Tags: java, android

Из [докумнентации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support#launch_adjacent) следует, что можно запустить intent в режиме "разделение экрана" с помощью флага `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACEN`. В версиях android 12+ устройство само войдет в режим "разделение экрана" и запустит intent. Но в версиях android меньше 12 устройство запустит intent только в том случае, если оно уже находится в режиме "разделение экрана".

Можно ли на устройствах с версией android меньше 12 запустить приложение в режиме "раздление экрана", если этот режим не был запущен?

Comment: Тут пишут что можно начиная с Андрод 7: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35986715/5479247

Answer (score 0):

Можно входить в режим "разделение экрана" с помощью `performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN)`

```
public class AccessibilityService extends android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService {
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }
}
```

После этого можно запустить intent с этими флагами:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```